# Execute ObjC function from NSstring

Tags: ios, objective-c

this is stupid question for execute some function in objC, for example like this:

```
NSString *function = @"-(void)execute{NSLog(@"123");}"
```

how to execute that string become a function?

Comment: why down vote? i'm asking simple question and need an answer

Comment: why would you want to do this? maybe elaborate on the problem as there is likely a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for,

**1. No Parameter**

```
SEL aSelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"execute");

[self performSelector:aSelector];
```

**Simulation:**

```
-(void)execute;
```

**2. Single Parameter**

```
SEL singleParamSelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"methodWithOneParam:");

[self performSelector:singleParamSelector
                    withObject:first];
```

**Simulation:**

```
-(void)methodWithOneParam:(NSString*)first;
```

**3. Multi Parameter**

```
SEL doubleParamSelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"methodWithFirst:andSecond:");

[self performSelector: doubleParamSelector
                    withObject: first
                    withObject: second];
```

**Simulation:**

```
-(void)methodWithFirst:(NSString*)first andSecond:(NSString*)second;
```

Comment: Won't (2) actually crash??? Because you are missing the `:` from your string.

Comment: @Popeye good catch, u could correct it :)

Comment: I'm not a fan of correcting code in answers, I prefer to just leave a comment and let them correct themselves. As I have had it in the past where someone has edited the code in my answer and they have just messed it up completely and I just don't want to do that to someone elses answer +1

Comment: its ok Popeye. Have a great day:)

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible, since Objective-C is compiled, not interpreted.

What you can do is add a `-(void)execute {...}` method in your code. Then if for some reason you need to call this method using a string, you can use `[self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"execute")]`.

But the string can not include any code. It must be limited to being an existing method's name.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please describe in detail, what you really want to do. What you describe pretty much looks like runtime code injection, if so just check the following docs about class_addMethod:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_addMethod

and check this good description:

http://distriqt.com/post/846

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. As the others have pointed out, you can create a selector from a string using NSSelectorFromString, and then you can use performSelector:withObject: or it's variants to invoke that method.